# Maven build on karaf - opendaylight

Tags: karaf, opendaylight

i am new to open daylight project.. i want to install open daylight controller and integrate my yang model with this .. so if i execute my POST query on controller it get responded.
i went through this tutorial

> https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/OpenDaylight_OpenFlow_Plugin::Running_controller_with_the_new_OF_plugin
>   to start karaf - but while building maven in the git clone ... cd
>   integration/distributions/extra/karaf mvn clean install.. step my
>   build is struck.. It remains in  '[DEBUG] Using connector
>   WagonRepositoryConnector with priority 0 for
>   ..nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/public/ Downloading:
>   ...nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/public/com/h2database/h2/1.4.185/h2-1.4.185.jar'
>   and build get failed.

Please help me resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I have understood correctly your question, but you can clone opendaylight controller project repository from:
https://github.com/opendaylight/controller

Just try with:
git clone https://github.com/opendaylight/controller.git

and once it be downloaded, you can try to compile it executing:
mvn clean install

I will add controller to .m2 repository.

Anyway, if you want to add any controller feature into your project, you can add it into your features.xml file, as follows:

```
<repository>mvn:org.opendaylight.controller/features-mdsal/${mdsal.version}/xml/features</repository>
```

That will add mdsal feature to your project.

And modify features/pom.xml with the next dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.opendaylight.controller</groupId>
  <artifactId>mdsal-artifacts</artifactId>
  <version>${mdsal.version}</version>
  <type>pom</type>
  <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

I hope that my info helps you. Let me know if you need more info.
Regards